# How can I get the data for each item in the listView using firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have made an app that gets data from the Firebase and I want when I click on the `listView` it shows me the data for each item but the problem is that when I click on an item in the `listView`, the `displayInformation` file opens but displays the last data uploaded to the firebase and does not display the data for each item in the `ListView`.

This is Firebase data:

```
{
  "List" : {
    "-Mmi2obH5ji14w82qUhR" : {
      "age" : 22,
      "description" : "blah",
      "firstName" : "John",
      "lastName" : "Michael"
    },
    "-MmiDkIXb_vLqET8BmKX" : {
      "age" : 24,
      "description" : "blah",
      "firstName" : "Leonardo",
      "lastName" : ""
    },
    "-MmnL1PYbcyW9VJPytr3" : {
      "age" : 19,
      "description" : "blah",
      "firstName" : "Mohamed",
      "lastName" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

These are My codes:

this is code for `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int LIST_APP_LOADER = 0;

    ArrayList<Informatin> listItem;
    ListView listView;
    listAppAdapter adapter;

    DatabaseReference reference;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String age;
    private String description;

    ArrayList<Informatin> mInformation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listItem = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayInformations.class);
            intent.putExtra("firstName", firstName);
            intent.putExtra("lastName", lastName);
            intent.putExtra("age", age);
            intent.putExtra("description", description);

            startActivity(intent);
        });

        LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(LIST_APP_LOADER, null, this);

        mInformation = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new listAppAdapter(this, mInformation);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("List");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mInformation.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    firstName = snapshot.child("firstName").getValue().toString();
                    lastName = snapshot.child("lastName").getValue().toString();
                    age = snapshot.child("age").getValue().toString();
                    description = snapshot.child("description").getValue().toString();

                    Informatin informatin = new Informatin(firstName, lastName, description, age);
                    mInformation.add(informatin);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_screen, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
this codes for `displayInformation` :
```

public class DisplayInformations extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {

```
private Uri mCurrentPersonUri;

private TextView mNameDisplay;
private TextView mAgeDisplay;
private TextView mDescriptionDisplay;
private ImageView mImageTopBar;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String age;
private String description;

private static final int EXISTING_LIST_APP_LOADER = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_informations);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    firstName = intent.getStringExtra("firstName");
    lastName = intent.getStringExtra("lastName");
    age = intent.getStringExtra("age");
    description = intent.getStringExtra("description");
    mCurrentPersonUri = intent.getData();

    loadListDetails();

    mNameDisplay = findViewById(R.id.name_display);
    mAgeDisplay = findViewById(R.id.age_display);
    mDescriptionDisplay = findViewById(R.id.description_display);
    mImageTopBar = findViewById(R.id.image_top_bar);

    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(EXISTING_LIST_APP_LOADER, null, this);
}

private void loadListDetails() {
            String name = firstName + " " + lastName;

            int ageInt = Integer.parseInt(age);
            setTitle(name);
            mNameDisplay.setText(name);
            if (age.equals("1")) {
                String ageDisplay = getString(R.string.age) + ": " + getString(R.string.one_year);
                mAgeDisplay.setText(ageDisplay);
            } else if (age.equals("2")) {
                String ageDisplay = getString(R.string.age) + ": " + getString(R.string.two_year);
                mAgeDisplay.setText(ageDisplay);
            } else if (ageInt >= 3 && ageInt <= 10) {
                String ageDisplay = getString(R.string.age) + ": " + age + getString(R.string.years);
                mAgeDisplay.setText(ageDisplay);
            } else if (ageInt >= 11) {
                String ageDisplay = getString(R.string.age) + ": " + age + getString(R.string.year);
                mAgeDisplay.setText(ageDisplay);
            }
            mDescriptionDisplay.setText(description);
        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display_informations, menu);
    return true;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        loadListDetails();

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mNameDisplay.setText("");
    mAgeDisplay.setText("");
    mDescriptionDisplay.setText("");
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows me the last data that was placed on the firebase"? What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo There are really no errors but the problem is in `setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: What exactly happens there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AlexMamo the problem is that when I click on an item in the listView, the displayInformation file opens but displays the last data uploaded to the firebase and does not display the data for each item in the listView

Comment: Show us what is the exact data you want to display on a click?

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the data in the post, please take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronous. This means that it takes some time until it becomes available in your app. Setting those variables as global doesn't solve the problem. What you need to do, is to get data from the adapter as an object of type `Informatin` and then add it to your Intent object. Assuming you already have getters for each field, please use the following lines of code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
    Informatin informatin = (Informatin) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayInformations.class);
    intent.putExtra("firstName", informatin.getFirstName());
    intent.putExtra("lastName", informatin.getLastName());
    intent.putExtra("age", informatin.getAge());
    intent.putExtra("description", informatin.getDescription());
    startActivity(intent);
});
```

Or you can add the entire `Informatin` object to the Intent, and not each field separately. To get it back, simply use [Intent#getSerializableExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)) method.

Please also note that your `age` field in the database is a number and **not** a String. So please change:

```
private String age;
```

Into:

```
private long age;
```

And:

```
age = snapshot.child("age").getValue().toString();
```

Into:

```
age = snapshot.child("age").getValue(Long.class);
```

Comment: I like your explanation, can you reply to this post please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742132/why-is-the-image-not-uploading-to-the-firebase-storage

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Comment: thank you very much